# create json login screen in storyboard in ios 6 for iphone

Tags: ios, json

I have tried many ways to achieve it but I it requires conditional segue for accepting the condition to match username and password and load the next view controller .I dont know how to achieve it in story board.
Please let me know any approach.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to start a segue from a button or a table view cell. You can start a segue from a view controller. This makes the segue available to the whole view controller by calling `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. You just need an action that does your test and then performs the segue.

```
- (IBAction)login:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (!self.user || !self.password) {
            // TODO: Display error
            return;
    }

    [self.model logInWithUser:self.user password:self.password completion:^{
        if (!self.model.authenticated) {
            // TODO: Display error
            return;
        }

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show Main View" sender:button];
    }];
}
```

Or whatever your logic for authentication is.

Comment: Thank you Jeffery.That was a great explanation.Is there any source code for only json login part where I could try it out on xcode.

Comment: I think your asking for an Apple provided API for authentication. This depends on the logic of your JSON service and I'm not aware of an Apple provided solution for this. You can use things like [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/) to cobble something together pretty quickly.

Comment: It checked AFNetworking its good.Let me know if there are any small source code for login and going to next screen.Thanks Jefferey for all the Help.

Answer (score 0):

It does not require conditional segue.

You should check credentials programmatically, say in your ViewController and call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on it. For this, connect your segue from the controller and give it an id.

Comment: Thanks ilmiacs for the reply It makes complete sense with the explanation given by Jefferey.Thanks again.